# Allowing a reader to annotate my gist with feedback

Tags: github, review

I'd like to create a gist of some ruby code of mine, for example with github, and then share it with a reviewer who will then be able to annotate lines with their code review notes. Is there a way to do this? I could not find it...

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar and found this: http://hpaste.org/

There you can paste your file contents, people can put comments in in it, you can view the diff etc.
It is not using github, but since you said "for example", maybe this is an option, too?

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange; it's made for this sort of thing.